# Access to Widget which is added to layout in other file

Tags: python, class, pyqt, pyside6

I'm trying to access a widget that is added to the layout in which it is displayed from another file.

ui_main.py

```
from ui_main_pages import Ui_MainPages

class UI_MainWindow(object):
    def setup_ui(self, parent):
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.central_widget_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.window = CustomWindow()
        self.central_widget_layout.addWidget(self.window)   

        # Add Left, Right, Title frames code ...
        
        self.content_area_frame = QFrame()
        self.content_area_layout = QHBoxLayout(self.content_area_frame)
        # Import pages from stacked widget
        self.load_pages = Ui_MainPages() 
        self.load_pages.setupUi(self.content_area_left_frame)
```

ui_main_pages.py

```
class Ui_MainPages(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainPages):
        self.main_pages_layout = QVBoxLayout(MainPages)
        self.pages = QStackedWidget(MainPages)
        self.page_1 = QWidget()
        # add page 1 code
        self.page_2 = QWidget()
        self.page_2_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea(self.page_2)
        self.contents = QWidget()
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.contents)
        self.title_label = QLabel(self.contents)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.title_label)
        self.description_label = QLabel(self.contents)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.description_label)

        self.row_1_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.row_1_layout.setObjectName(u"row_1_layout")
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.row_1_layout)

        self.row_2_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.row_2_layout.setObjectName(u"row_2_layout")
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.row_2_layout)

        self.row_3_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.row_3_layout.setObjectName(u"row_3_layout")
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.row_3_layout)

        self.row_4_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.row_4_layout.setObjectName(u"row_4_layout")
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.row_4_layout)

        self.row_5_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.row_5_layout.setObjectName(u"row_5_layout")
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.row_5_layout)

        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.contents)

        self.page_2_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

        self.pages.addWidget(self.page_2)
```

Where i add the table widget is in the page_2 to row_5_layout, lets see in the next code

setup_main_window.py

```
from ui_main import UI_MainWindow

class SetupMainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # SETUP MAIN WINDOw
        # Load widgets from "gui\uis\main_window\ui_main.py"
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        self.ui = UI_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setup_ui(self)

    def setup_gui(self):
        # OBJECTS FOR LOAD PAGES

        # PAGE 1 - ADD LOGO TO MAIN PAGE
        self.logo_svg = QSvgWidget(Functions.set_svg_image("logo_home.svg"))
        self.ui.load_pages.logo_layout.addWidget(self.logo_svg, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.AlignCenter)

        # PAGE 2
        # TABLE WIDGETS
        self.table_widget = PyTableWidget()
        self.ui.load_pages.row_5_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
```

In the above file I add the table widget to the layout in ui_main_pages, and in the next file I try load a html file a make a pandas dataframe, then set a custom model to table_widget

app_file.py

```
from ui_main import UI_MainWindow

class Files:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # IMPORT WIDGETS
        self.ui = UI_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setup_ui()

    def load(self):
        global file_name
        # FILE DIALOG
        dlg_file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent=self, caption=self.tr("Select a file"),filter=self.tr('HTML Files (*.html)'),)

        # READ FILE
        if dlg_file:
            self.df_squad = FMi.setting_up_pandas(dlg_file[0])
            # FMi is a custom package, which read the file and convert it to a dataframe
            # self.df_squad is the dataframe

        # Below i try to select the table_widget created before and edit it
        self.ui.load_pages.row_5_layout.table_widget.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        model = CustomPandasModel(self.df_squad)
        self.ui.load_pages.row_5_layout.table_widget.setModel(model)
```

I have already connected a button to load function in Files class, and it works up to the line of "setSelectionBehavior".

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout' object has no attribute 'table_widget'
```

EDIT

The last file `main.py` from where I run all the project

```
from ui_main import UI_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = UI_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setup_ui(self)
        # SETUP MAIN WINDOW
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        SetupMainWindow.setup_gui(self)
        self.show()

    def btn_clicked(self):
        # GET BT CLICKED
        btn = SetupMainWindow.setup_btns(self)
        # Here i have the code to change pages like next example
        # HOME BTN
        if btn.objectName() == "btn_home":
            # Select Menu
            self.ui.left_menu.select_only_one(btn.objectName())

            # Load Page 1
            MainFunctions.set_page(self, self.ui.load_pages.page_1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # APPLICATION
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.ico"))
    window = MainWindow()

    # EXEC APP
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Github project link
https://github.com/truev0/FM_Excel_Helper

Comment: The `self.ui` in `SetupMainWindow` and the `self.ui` in `Files` are completely unrelated.  If you expect both of them to use the same `UI_MainWindow`, then you need to create that outside of these classes and pass the instance in.

Comment: Attributes created for widgets (and layouts) are always set for the form class, not hierarchically. Change to `self.ui.load_pages.table_widget` and so on. Besides, you're not supposed to edit pyuic files, but instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you guide me a little bit more, i have added a fifth file,  `main.py` which import fom ui_main the class `UI_MainWindow`

Comment: You have a fairly major design problem here.  Which object is the "main window"?  I think it is `MainWindow`, but then what are the other things?  They aren't derived from Qt classes, so they can't be windows.  Is `UI_MainWindow` supposed to be a window?  Is `SetupMainWIndow` supposed to be a window?  Is `File`?  Or are all of these things just holding simple functions that actually need to be part of `MainWindow`?

Comment: @VictorCaicedo actually, after reading again your code (which is a bit convoluted, and overcomplicated, I must say), that `table_widget` is set for `self`, and since you're *not* creating instances of those strange classes (which is good, as `Files` would throw an exception), the `self` is coincidentally the `MainWindow` instance itself, so it is actually `self.table_widget` (since you created it so). In any case, as said, your code is overly and unnecessarily complicated, those classes don't seem to be very useful (or useful at all). Don't exaggerate encapsulation, it's pointless, like this.

Comment: @TimRoberts `UI_MainWindow` is the .ui file from designerconverted to .py, but made manually. And yes, simple functions to be part of `MainWindow`

Comment: @musicamante As you have seen in my previous questions, I am trying to get started with this, if there is a way I can simplify it a little more, I am totally open to receive it and adapt it.

Comment: @VictorCaicedo there's no point in trying to make UI files mimicking the behavior of pyuic. You either use the original (and **unmodified**) pyuic objects by following the guidelines linked above, or you build the UI in the `__init__` of a Qt widget subclass. The fact is that *you* are complicating things: those classes are completely useless (and creating separated files is even more pointless). Just implement those functions in the QMainWindow subclass of your last file, you'll only need two files: the pyuic file, and your custom subclass that will use it and implement the other functions.

Comment: @musicamante I have added the project link if you can take a look and how it works

Comment: The key takeaway is what I said above: all the functions in `SetupMainWindow` and in `File` should just be functions within `MainWindow`.  They are not working with a separate object.

Comment: @VictorCaicedo That link is a 404.